# Не принимает файл на сервер php

Tags: php, сервер, post

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так.

Есть POST форма, примитивная, ждет 1 файл

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <?php
        // UPLOAD_ERR_OK | Значение: 0; Ошибок не возникало, файл был успешно загружен на сервер.
        if ($_FILES && $_FILES['filename']['error']== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
        {
            $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name);
            echo "Файл загружен";
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputFile">Пожалуйтса, загрузите текстовый файл</label>
                <input type="file" name="filename" id="exampleInputFile">
                <p class="help-block">Вы сможете загрузить только текстовые документы</p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Загрузить на сервер</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но я никогда не вижу echo строки, а значит файл никогда не загружается на сервер...что делать?( Да и в папке с проектом он отсутствует.

Comment: в какую папку перемещаете то? в `$name` небось содержится не полный путь с директорией, а просто имя.

Comment: по умолчанию в корневую папку проекта, я потом уже буду создавать разные директории

Comment: вставьте перед проверкой `print_r($_FILES);`
вполне возможно, что $_FILES['filename'] - это массив, и в проверке нужно использовать `$_FILES['filename'][0]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK`

Comment: `display_errors` и `error_reporting(E_ALL)` вам в помощь, вдовесок к комментарию выше.